# Java OffsetDateTime precision issue in tests on different environments

Tags: java, h2, spock

I am running tests in Spock in which I try to compare two OffsetDateTime objects. Tests are integrated with H2 database. My entity is named Beacon and it has creation_time property. This is the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "beacons")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Beacon {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    private OffsetDateTime creationTime;
}
```

Then, the Spock test, I do the following things: I create new Beacon object:

```
def beacon = new Beacon(
        id: id,
        creationTime: OffsetDateTime.now()
)
```

then I save the Beacon object in the database, I fetch it and compare creationTimes:

```
beaconRepository.save(beacon)
def savedBeacon = beaconRepository.findById(id)
beacon.getCreationTime() == savedBeacon.getCreationTime()
```

And now, everything works correctly on Unix and MacOS, whereas on Windows this test fails, as savedBeacon.getCreationTime() returns more precise time than beacon.getCreationTime(). Why is it so? Of course, I know several workarounds, like e.g. defining creationTime as `OffsetDateTime.now(Clock.tickMillis(ZoneId.systemDefault()))`, but is there any better solution?

Comment: Your "workaround" is exactly how you should do it. Why do you think it's not a good enough solution?

Comment: I thought that it might be some overflow...

Comment: Edit your Question to report what version of Java is deployed on each of your computers: `System.getProperty("java.version")`. And post real example data you found.

Answer (score 3):

How exactly your column is defined in the database? It should have `TIMESTAMP(9) WITH TIME ZONE` data type, otherwise values will be rounded to microseconds.

The SQL Standard requires the default fractional seconds precision for `TIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data types to be 6.

Various `.now()` methods in Java 8 return up to 3 fractional digits. Since Java 9 they usually return 6 or 7 digits depending on OS and may potentially return more digits in the future (on Linux, for example, 9 digits is available, but Java currently takes only 6).

JSR-310 data types support up to 9 digits. Some DBMS, including the H2, also support up to 9 digits (and few support even more). But some other DBMS support only up to 6 digits.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [OffsetDateTime.isEqual()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#isEqual-java.time.OffsetDateTime-) since it compares [Instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) representation of your dates, which is what you're actually aiming at.

Comment: I believe that it doesn't change the result - objects differ in precision, so isEqual will return false as well

Comment: Please look at the source of isEqual(), it would answer your concern. SPOILER - it unifies the percision.

Comment: where is this unification of precision? ```public boolean isEqual(OffsetDateTime other) {
        return toEpochSecond() == other.toEpochSecond() &&
                toLocalTime().getNano() == other.toLocalTime().getNano();
    }```

Comment: Exactly there - everything is translated to nano seconds accuracy.

Comment: If a timestamp only has second precision, then `getNano()` will simply return `0`, while the other timesamp will return something different from `0` so has wojtekt said, it wont help you. You'd have to go the other way around and truncate the other timestamp to the same precision. The basic principle also applies if one timestamp has only milli/microsecond precision.